# Raiils 7.1.3 and ruby 3.30

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I run rails new hallo_app it creates app for ruby 3.0, which doesn't support openssl 3.0
Ruby 3.3.0 doesn't support I've got a error

```
The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.

    from /snap/ruby/323/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:606:in `block in try_compile'
    from /snap/ruby/323/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:555:in `with_werror'
    from /snap/ruby/323/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:606:in `try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:6:in `block in have_builtin_func'
    from /snap/ruby/323/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:983:in `block in checking_for'
    from /snap/ruby/323/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:344:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /snap/ruby/323/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:314:in `open'
    from /snap/ruby/323/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:344:in `block in postpone'
    from /snap/ruby/323/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:314:in `open'
    from /snap/ruby/323/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `postpone'
    from /snap/ruby/323/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:982:in `checking_for'
    from extconf.rb:5:in `have_builtin_func'
    from extconf.rb:18:in `<main>'
```

https://gist.github.com/Tusenka/adfe252c8bbef9e0763caef625374dd4

Can I generate app for ruby 3.3.0?

Comment: _"You have to install development tools first."_ 

Comment: if you're on a Mac, you not only need to have Xtools installed, but you need to agree to the license terms, so you need to open Xtools and you should be prompted to agree to the license.

Comment: You state it creates an app for Ruby 3.0 ("rails new hallo_app it creates app for **ruby 3.0**"), then you mention  "**Ruby 3.3.0** doesn't support", then your stack trace shows ruby 3.2.3 "**ruby/323**". Then you ask how to generate an app for 3.3.0? Have you tried installing 3.3.0 and then installing rails and then generating the app?